# 新しいタグの許可の要望: google-app-engine

Tags: 討議, 完了

タグのgoogleappengineをgoogle-app-engineに変更しようとして、以下のようなエラーになりました。

> タグ [google-app-engine] を作成しようとしていますが、タグ [googleappengine] はすでに存在します!この新しいタグの許可が必要な場合は、メタで取り上げてください。

[googleappengine] はすこし読みづらく、また英語版は [google-app-engine] を使用しているようなので、変更を要望したいのですが、どうでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

新規に [google-app-engine](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine) タグを作り、 [googleappengineをそのシノニムに設定しました](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/google-app-engine/synonyms)。